# PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet how to make row visible during generation

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I create new rows in excel using the insertNewRowBefore method, then I set their size, forbid folding and make them clearly visible through as a result, only the address specified in the line inside the template is displayed at startup, the rest are displayed only when you click on them

Code:

```
    $rowNumber = 18;
    $sheet->insertNewRowBefore($rowNumber+1, $fp->count());
    foreach($fp as $index=> $point) {
        $sheet->mergeCells("C{$rowNumber}:K{$rowNumber}")->getRowDimension($rowNumber)->setRowHeight(50)->setCollapsed(false)->setVisible(true);
        $sheet->setCellValue("C{$rowNumber}", $point->company . ' ' . $point->address);
        $rowNumber++;
    }
```